# Issue with Bundling and Minification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrease

I am trying to use the asp.net **bundling and minification** feature. The issue is when i am including the jquery ui custom script in the bundle than the script is not rendering in my layout page. The code is:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
         "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.custom.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/jquery").Include(
            "~/Content/jquery-ui-{version}.custom.css"));
```

The above both CSS and script is not including. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I think it's called `Bundling and Minification` because the scripts are bundled and minified (the white spaces and line breaks are removed).

Comment: How do you add the references to these bundles in your views or layout page?

Comment: thanks for pointing but it was a typo

Comment: I'm looking for assistance with this same problem. I'm using Visual Web Developer 2012 and I've created an MVC4 application which has Bundling and Minification already. Adding the reference to the file on the Layout page as @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") is not 'causing my JQuery to work. Anyone have further input that might help?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've created the bundles, you'll need to add them to your HTML somewhere. Usually in the **_Layout.cshtml**, you'll need a line like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: I have Visual Web Developer 2012 and, thus, Bundling and Minification is already installed. So, as you mentioned, I added the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") to the Layout file. The jquery I've tested is not working and I can't figure out for the life of me why not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One more option to debug the issue is installing the fiddler and checking the files downloaded while making the request for the webpage Just click on the missing file name in the fiddler and check what is the content returned. In my case it returned the error message Could not load file or assembly WebGrease. I have removed and added the reference and now the script files are rendered.